# GPU rendering doesn´t work on Win32 latest builds. Any clue about it?

Tags: rendering, gpu

On the latest builds the option for GPU rendering is missing. This is something that doesn´t happen on the official version. Any clue on what´s happening here?

Comment: see latest developer notes, featured on BN: http://www.blendernation.com/2015/12/20/57205/ Ton writes: "32 bits versions of Blender might have had their longest time"

Comment: As far as I know CUDA 7.5 don´t work for win 32 bits. Does this mean that CUDA rendering won´t no longer be supported for 32 bits?